# Откуда берется объект, если я передал в контексте масив?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

У меня есть пока-что пустой масив в главном компоненте, который я передаю, как контекст, в дочерние компоненты:

```js
const PatientContext = createContext([{}]);

function App() {
  const [selectedPatient, setSelectedPatient] = useState([]);
  const [patients, setPatients] = useState([]);

  async function patientsHasChanged() {
        const patientService = new PatientService();
        const loadedPatients = await patientService.getPatients();
        setPatients(loadedPatients);
};

  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <PatientContext.Provider value={[selectedPatient, setSelectedPatient, patients, patientsHasChanged]}>
        <Sidebar />
        <Content />
      </PatientContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

И в дочернем компоненте я пытаюсь с этим масивом работать:

```js
const Sidebar = () => {
    const [patients, selectedPatient, setSelectedPatient] = useContext(PatientContext);

    return (
        <div className='sidebar'>
            <div className='search'>
                <input type="text" placeholder='Search' />
                <a href="/TechTask/new"><button>New patient</button></a>
            </div>
            <div className='list'>
                <ul>
                    {patients.map((p) =>
                        <li onClick={setSelectedPatient}>
                            <div className='name'>
                                {p.name}
                            </div>
                            <div className='age'>
                                {p.age}
                            </div>
                        </li>)
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Но получаю ошибку

> TypeError: patients.map is not a function

Обычно, такая ошибка у меня появляется, когда я пытаюсь использовать `map` для не масивов, но тут то я явно пытаюсь передать масив, как контекст. Я решил посмотреть через `console.log(patients)` что там на самом деле хранится и увидел там объект `{}`. Вопрос: откуда он берется и как это исправить, т.к это не должно так работать?

Comment: Вы проверяли `Array.isArray(patients)`?

Comment: Да, получаю false т.к проблема в контексте из-за того, что почему-то возвращается пустой объект. UPD: Если в компоненте App, то все ок, там масив, но уже в дочерних - не ок, тк уже не масив

Comment: Нарушен порядок элементов в массиве, у Вас в провайдере `patients` идет третьим, а через `useContext` вы его забираете первым. Почему не используете объект? Все-равно достаете из контекста не все элементы в том же сайдбаре

Comment: Исправил на: в `App` добавил `const patientContext = {selectedPatient, setSelectedPatient, patients, patientsHasChanged}` и соотвественно в контекст передаю эту переменную, но теперь если пытаюсь вытянуть из контекста что-то, то получаю `undefined`

Comment: Покажите, как Вы вытаскиваете переменные из контекста в Sidebar.

Comment: `const patientContext = useContext(PatientContext);`. По идее, как я описывал в предыдущем комменте, я должен получить объект и уже к его полям я мог бы легко обращаться, но почему-то получаю undefined